# Run hadoop job when data insertion in hbase

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, oozie, hadoop2

I need to run a hadoop job whenever an insertion done on hbase table? There are some schedulers available

1. Apache Oozie
2. Fair scheduler

Which one I can choose for my purpose?

Answer (score 1):

**Apache Oozie** is a **Workflow Scheduler**, which is used for designing jobs workflow and coordinating them to occur at certain event or as designed in control flow. Jobs can be map-reduce, Streaming map-reduce, Pig, Hive, Sqoop task as well as java program and shell scripts.

And **Fair Scheduler** is used as **resource scheduler** for MapReduce jobs.

Now for your case, you should use Oozie.